# Ajax posting using rails 4.0 for commenting on the ForumThread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am developing an simple forum application using rails 4.0. I want my comments to be posted as Ajax rather than reloading an entire page please help me. 
This is my show.html.erb for forum

```
 <div id="topic_content">
  <h1>
   <%= @topic.title %>
  </h1>
  <p>
    <%= @topic.content %>
  </p>
  <div id="comments">
   <h2>
    <%= @topic.comments.count %>
    Comments
   </h2>
   <%= render @topic.comments %>
   <%if user_signed_in? && current_user.user? %>
   <h3>Reply to thread</h3>
   <%= render "comments/form" %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
 <br/>
 <hr/>
 <br/>
 <%if user_signed_in?%>
 <% if can? :update, @topic %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_path(@topic), class: "button" %> 
 <% end %>


<% if can? :delete, @topic %>
 <%= link_to "Delete", topic_path(@topic), method: :delete, data: {      confirm: "Are you sure you want to do this?" }, class: "button" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>

</div>
```

And this is my _comment.html.erb partial

```
<div class="comment clearfix">
<div class="content">
 <p class="comment_content">
   <%= comment.comment %>
 </p>

</div>
<div class="buttons">
<%if user_signed_in?%>
<% if can? :update, @topic => Comment %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_comment_path(comment.topic, comment) %>
<% end %>
<% if can? :delete, @topic => Comment %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", [comment.topic, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: where's the rest of your code?

Comment: which files do you require please tell me so that i can post it ? i think these two files are enough ..........

Comment: the ajax comment is usually done in controller with js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use server-generated JavaScript and a remote form.

1. Add `remote: true` to your form
2. Prepare your controller to respond with JavaScript:

   ```
   # CommentsController

   def create
     @comment = @topic.comments.create!(comment_params)
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to @comment } # no js fallback
       format.js   # renders comments/create.js.erb
     end
   end
   ```
3. Create the `create.js.erb` template:

   ```
   # comments/create.js.erb

   $('#comments').prepend('<%=j render @comment %>');
   ```

   What happens here is we tell Rails to render our comment (using the comment partial) as JavaScript-ready string (notice the `<%=j`), and we're creating JS that will prepend this new comment, rendered, to the beginning of the `comments` div. Do experiment with what you can do with this JS response; it's run in the context of the page with the form, so you can have a lot of fun with that.

Also read the article at https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3697-server-generated-javascript-responses - this is where I learned this technique, and you will no doubt find the similarities between the example code for your case and their example code.